# JSF, Spring application: Different users see the same view

Tags: java, spring, session, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF 2.1, Primeface 3.2, Spring/Spring security 3.05 web application. I signin with an account and do some UI manipulation (button click, some ajax actions, etc). I logout and then login with another user, I see the same view (means the same state after the manipulations done by the previous user)

I tried some tricks like change the scope to request, invalide session, set face redirect to true after logout, set javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD to client etc. but nothing works.

Edit 1: Tried using different browers with different users the same time I see the same view.

Edit 2:

Scenario 1: I have a  with a list of checkbox, I tick some checkbox and then I click a  who fire a event of a managedBean (actionListener="#{xxxxxMB.doSomething}") and I logout and login, the checkboxs keep ticked,

Scenario 2: the same  I tick some checkbox and then I logout and login, the checkboxs are not ticked.

Comment: Are you sure it is not an issue of your browser cache?

Comment: Don't think so, tried clean cache already, and even use different browers with different users, i see the same views :(

Comment: By any change do you store some user data in the business layer, I guess you are putting some user info in a singleton bean so at the end every one is sharing that info. Also, what is the backing bean scope of that view?

Comment: the views have no dependency on user info. and I dont store user specific data, all backing beans are @RequestScoped. noticed jsf store the ui state only after some ajax call, like autocomplete, button click etc.

Comment: What kind of manipulations? Please provide examples, visual is better.

Comment: scenario 1: I have a <p:selectManyCheckbox> with a list of checkbox, I tick some checkbox and then I click a <p:commandButton> who fire a event of a managedBean (actionListener="#{xxxxxMB.doSomething}") and I logout and login, the checkboxs keep ticked,
scenario 2: the same <p:selectManyCheckbox> I tick some checkbox and then I logout and login, the checkboxs are not ticked.

Comment: @Chinsa If the value of the selectManyCheckbox is truly a managed property of a RequestScoped bean then any new request, ajax or otherwise will result in that managedproperty reverting back to their default value, UNLESS during the instantiation of that ManagedBean, you are loading persisted data from a data store and assigning the managed property a value.

Comment: @maple_shaft, selectManyCheckbox's value is a property(List<xxx>) of the requestscoped managed bean. you mean i have to reset all stored data each time? if it's the case, where to put the reset? before logout or after login? thx

Comment: post some code snippets in your question, at least we would need examples of the ManagedBeans you interact with and faces-config.xml

Comment: Im not sure if this will help you but I have experience that the requestscope do not handle propertly the ajax calls, could you try to define the bean as viewscope to see how behaves.

Comment: Do you:
1) everywhere use ViewScoped beans
2) are awere that spring beans by default are singletons?